# Merging Features with Equal Values in one Attribute Table Field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, merge, fields-attributes

I'm trying to merge all the features in a shapefile that have the same value under a certain field in the attribute table. Right now, I open the attribute table and use "Select by Attributes" to select all the features of a certain value, merge those, then move on to the next value.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: You can use Dissolve tool instead and select the field that you want to merge (dissolve) all lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dissolve tool selecting the attribute that you want to merge.